# Select query in trigger sql server syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 / 2008R2 / 2012 syntax please !

```
ALTER TRIGGER WriteToLoggOnRep
ON dbo.UNITs 
FOR UPDATE
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @changed INT
DECLARE @departmentid INT

IF (UPDATE (DEPARTMENTID))  

<!-- info -->
//if a departmentid was change on a unit, that is the case if a unit is sendt to maintenance.(and in other cases, change dep. etc)
//then a new deparmentid is set, the deparmentid set is the MAINTENANCEDEPARTMENTID for the current location
//This integer value will korrenspondere to a DEPARTMENID int the DEPARTMENTs table and 
// a MAINTENANCEDEPARTMENTID in the LOCATIONs table.
// The challenge is to find out whether this id is actually a maintenance id/ maintenance department or not..
// ALL maintenance departments are named MAINTENANCE in the DEPARTMENTs table
// Departments are related/connected to location and not universal among locations
// All Locations have a "MAINTENANCE" and a "IN STOCK" department created initially


 SELECT DEPARTMENNAME FROM DEPARTMENTs WHERE DEPARTMENTID = UPDATE.DEPARTMENTID INTO @DepartmentName;

 IF(@DepartmentName = 'MAINTENANCE')

        SELECT @changed = COUNT(*) FROM Inserted i INNER JOIN Deleted d
                        ON i.UNITID = d.UNITID WHERE ISNULL(i.UNITID,'') = @departmentid

                        IF(@changed > 0)

INSERT INTO LOGGs
                         (DATE, NOTE, UNITID)
SELECT       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'SENDT TO Maintenance', UNITID

                        FROM inserted
END
END

<!----->
```

Purpose of trigger:
Write to the logg if a unit is sendt to maintenance and stamp it with some information:
(I am also making a similar for back from maintenance)
- `curr Datetime`
-"Sendt to maintenance"
- `UNITID` (the id of the unit that is sendt to maintenance

Tables involved:

```
UNITs
UNITID (AI) (P)
SERIALNR
DEPARTMENTID*

DEPARTMENTs
DEPARTMENTID (AI) (P)
DEPARTMENTNAME (Of course, there are several departments called maintenance)
LOCATIONID*

LOCATIONs
LOCATIONID (AI) (P)
LOCATIONNAME
MAINTENANCEDEPARTMENTID (for that current location)
INSTOCKDEPARTMENTID (for that current location)
```

I need to grab a value from the table `DEPARTMENTs` , column `DEPARTMENTID` (`INT` auto inc.)

For the department that is

I hope and think this is "close", but the compiler is marking problems @ several locations...

I have also consider including this writing to the log to the query that is sending the unit to maintenance?

However, it is nicer to have a standalone trigger to modify this?

It may well be there is an easier and better way to solve this? I'm open to suggestions!
If I haven't supplied enough information, let me know!

SQL Server 2008 / 2008R2 / 2012 syntax please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by integrating this in a stored function, which is called from the query that is sending the unit to maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

A casual glance at the code notes that this is not valid SQL Server syntax:

```
SELECT DEPARTMENNAME FROM DEPARTMENTs WHERE DEPARTMENTID = UPDATE.DEPARTMENTID INTO @DepartmentName;
```

Try this:

```
SELECT @DepartmentName = DEPARTMENNAME
FROM DEPARTMENTs
WHERE DEPARTMENTID = UPDATE.DEPARTMENTID ;
```

That might fix your problem.